# SubSampling data such that at least K classes are selected from a huge dataset containing N classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, sampling

I have a dataset containing 1.3 Million records categorized into 109 classes. Obviously there is class imbalance with highest class being 18% in the data and lowest class being less than 1%

Now, my task is to devise a general forumula/technique/code for sampling from these reords such that: What is the minimum number of records we need to select such that it contains records from K classes (where K can vary from 1 to 109) and is representetive of the original data for these classes. Obviuosly tehre cant be an exact solution so we can deal with 'high confidence' solution

Comment: what do you mean by representative? Did you mean that proportions in your sample are the same as proportions in your set? If you have 7 records of class 1 and 13 records of class 2, the proportion is 7:13, so you will have to select all of them (prime numbers do not have common divisors).

Comment: Not exactly in that sense. An analogy would be : In general we say that  randomly seeecting 10% of the sample from a large sample is gud enough to get an idea about the overall data. In that sense. If you have any approach eve  without considering this 'representative' thing, please tell

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a simple combinatorics problem.
Assume you have M red marbles and N green marbles in a box. You pull out K marbles randomly. What is the expected values of a ratio of red to green in your sample? Furthermore, what is the variance? Lets define "representative" as extreme values in 95% confidence interval of the ratio (expected-2*std, expected+2*std) been no more than 10% wide relative to the expected value of the ratio. It as straightforward to express it as a function of K (in fact you can do it with pencil and paper for 2 classes). For three classes you can say that the highest variance of the ratio between any two classes should be no more than 10%.